# Copy protection and pay per installation on different device

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-lvl

I want with my app such that user can not copy it. and user must pay for an app when user install on different mobile.

Once user paid app then it should work only in one mobile. when user install the app with same login then user can not install the app on different mobile. For this user need to pay for this.

How to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this through Google Play's paid app feature.

At best, you can make your app free and have an in app purchase that the user must make, which ties the device IMEI or MAC Address to that purchase on a server you own. That way, you can make users buy the app everytime they install it on a new device.

The copy protection feature is now deprecated, and you can't use it. Additionally, any user with a rooted device can pull your apk off their device. This is outside your control.

Comment: To achieve my first requirement i need to setup my own server..right?

Comment: copy protection is deprecated now is there any alternative for this.